# HDMI switches, preferably that support 4K @ 30 fps or better and that can be used in either direction

Tags: video, kvm, 4k, video-adapters

Looking at such switches on Amazon, I see many of them and I'm really wondering whether a $10 unit can really support 4K at all...

Right now, I need this to send my Raspberry Pi to either my monitor or a capture card. So one input and two outputs. Later, I'm much more likely to use it the other way around: my Raspberry Pi & my two Jetsons to one monitor.

The Raspberry Pi is an old model (a.k.a. Pi 3), but the Jetsons support full 4K so that's why I'm thinking to get a switch that really supports 4K and is bidirectional (aren't all switches bidirectional anyway? if not, why not?).

Comment: HDMI "switches" are devices that let you toggle between multiple ports, so you can have multiple things connected to one port on a TV and use an actual hardware switch to select which one is connected. I think those can be used in reverse to have one device go to multiple different screens? As long as it's physically connecting only two ports together it should be bi-directional. Some "switches" are a lot more featured and may have one-sided behaviour because of a chipset that expects the signal to come from one specific port and processes it.

Comment: Yeah, I've [found one](https://www.amazon.com/JSAUX-Aluminum-Bi-Directional-Splitter-Compatible/dp/B08JTZB2YC) which seems way too cheap to support 4K... and is specifically marked as a bi-directional one. But many have features that seem to say that if there is no "input" then that port is essentially turned off (electronically). So I'm thinking that those are not going to be bi-directional...

Comment: 4K video at 30Hz is just HDMI 1.4 (using the max bandwidth for that version).
With the way a switch works, there's very little that can be done to make it *not* support 4K. It's just supposed to be connecting two ports wire-to-wire and hopefully shield the intermediate wiring from emf. This one looks like it's a "smart" switch so it may have lots of ways that it goes wrong and doesn't work bidirectionally. You want to find a switch that physically toggles the signal path between two ports.